# how to run ruby gem like run java jar

Tags: java, ruby, jar, rubygems

I'm a new comer to ruby, but with some experience of java. I can run a java program on windows by a bat file.

> java -jar Example.jar

and here i get a gem(something like jar in java), for example, t1.gem.
I wonder if there is a way run gem like

> ruby -gem t1.gem

Comment: I'm confused. You normally use `gem install` and then [`require` the code](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#requiring-code).

Comment: I have get your idea. But what I have to do after I wrote many .rb file. Should I use the whole directory every time so that I can start a rb file, which is the entrance of the project. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: You can run the `rb` file, like `ruby file.rb` Where `file.rb` is the entrance you define.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an executable that is installed on people's system when they install your gem.

Add this line to your `example.gemspec` file

```
...
gem.executables = ['hello_worlds']
...
```

And then have a file named `hello_worlds` in your gem that starts with a shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "Hello, worlds!"
```

The first line of that file makes it an executable.

People can then run your gem with

```
> gem install example
> hello_worlds
```

Comment: Tanks. It's works in Linux. But the operation install a gem into system, and I see it as a side-affect. I'm looking for another way.